# DISTINCT QUERY on PARTITION KEY Of Table

Tags: sql, hive

If I am querying distinct on some column of a table which is the partition key of that table, will it scan whole data inside those partitions or will give result from partition metadata.

Answer (score 0):

No it won't get data simply from partition metadata. It will scan data but if your tables metadata like column stats and partition stats are upto date and running query with following properties, it should take less time (or scanning less data) to get distinct values on partition column

```
set hive.cbo.enable=true;
set hive.compute.query.using.stats=true;
set hive.stats.fetch.column.stats=true;
set hive.stats.fetch.partition.stats=true;
```